# Ignore max and min values in plotly Box plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataset with high variance and I really just want to look at the 25, 50, and 75 quartile. How do I remove the max and min values from displaying in go.Box? I tried brute force set yaxis_range but it looks really ugly.

```
fig = go.Figure(layout_yaxis_range=[-100, 100])
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    x=df.date,
    y=df.vals,
    name="Only Whiskers",
    boxpoints=False, # no data points
    marker_color='rgb(9,56,125)',
    line_color='rgb(9,56,125)'
))
```

Comment: is `df` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes it is @Chillie

Comment: Does it have to be box plot? If not, you could overlap scatter plots (for example) with y=df.vals.quantile(.25), y=df.vals.quantile(.5), y=df.vals.quantile(.75)

EDIT: Also, boxpoints=False means it extends to the full range of points, I think it goes agaisnt what you are trying to acchieve, try 'suspectedoutliers' if you have not already